# How to plot two lists of tuples with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two lists where each element is a tuple that should be interpreted as

```
x = [(x1_begin, x1_end), (x2_begin, x2_end), ... , (xn_begin, xn_end)]
y = [(y1_begin, y1_end), (y2_begin, y2_end), ... , (yn_begin, yn_end)]
```

In one figure, I would like to plot all these points and draw lines *only* between `(yi_begin, yi_end)` vs `(xi_begin, xi_end)` for all i.

The following code manages to plot all the points. But I'm not sure how to draw the lines properly between the points. Any help is much appreciated.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [(1, 27), (32, 55), (56, 80), (84, 103)]
y = [(5, 7), (3, 6), (4, 9), (6, 11)]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.scatter(x, y, color='black')
plt.show()
```

Comment: I am a bit confused. Is your x and y corresponding to coordinates on the x, y axis?

Comment: @Spinor8 yes, so the range of the x-axis should be 1 to 103, and of the y-axis 3 to 11. I hope that clarifies your question?

Comment: So your data is essentially: list_1 = [(line1_start_x, line1_end_x) ,.... ] and list_2 = [(line1_start_y, line1_end_y) ....], right?

Comment: (yi_begin, yi_end) vs (xi_begin, xi_end) means a line between (xi_begin,yi_begin) to (xi_end,yi_end) ?

Comment: In the example code above, you'd expect 4 lines, right?

Comment: Also, seems like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35363444/plotting-lines-connecting-points). Please use search before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over your tuples:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [(1, 27), (32, 55), (56, 80), (84, 103)]
y = [(5, 7), (3, 6), (4, 9), (6, 11)]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
for xt, yt in zip(x,y):
    ax.plot(xt, yt, color='black')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If indeed you are asking for one line per tuple, here's the code.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
assert len(x) == len(y)
for i in range(len(x)):
    plt.plot(x[i], y[i])
plt.show()
```

giving you

[image]