# Generate random triangles inside a 5x5 square and plot them

Tags: python, math

I am unable to generate a random triangle inside the 5x5 square. Then find the area and perimeter of that random triangle.

I have to use basic python so below is what code I have tried.

```py
from random import *
from math import *

#ask the user for how many triangles they want to test
trials = int(input("How many random triangles would you like to test? "))

#Create the 5x5 square
square = []
for length in range(5):
    square.append([])
for width in range(5):
    square[length].append("0")

for triangle in range(trials):
    x = randint(0, len(square)-1)
    y = randint(0, len(square[0])-1)
```

I am looking for the code that will allow a random triangle to be plotted within the square.

Comment: The common way to display things on the screen in Python 3.x is to use the built-in [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function.

Comment: You haven't included anything that displays output: `print`, or a plot, or any such thing.  You do some computations and the print without any return communication.

Comment: My apologies, i reworded the question.

Comment: Plotting isn't really basic python functionality. Which library do you want to use?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `print` command in the for loop. Whatever you want to print, put as `print(x, y)` ( or print x,y ) depending if you are using python 3 or 2 respectively.

Look into matplotlib and search for some examples how to plot a line between to `(x, y)` vectors. That should be it.

Here's an example
[Plotting lines connecting points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35363444/plotting-lines-connecting-points)